# Changing button sizes for screen sizes Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, layout, screen-size

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.andrewfinlay.vectorcalculator.MainActivity"
                tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:password="false"
        android:phoneNumber="false"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/resultOutput"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/resultOutput"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/x1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:hint="x1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/x2"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/x2"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:hint="x2"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/x3"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/x3"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:hint="x3"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/y1"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/y1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:hint="y1"
            android:focusable="true"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/y2"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/y2"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:hint="y2"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/y3"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/y3"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:hint="y3"
            android:focusable="true"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="Add"
            android:id="@+id/addButton"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:background="#3F51B5"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="Sub"
            android:id="@+id/subButton"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:background="#3F51B5"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="Unit"
            android:id="@+id/unitButton"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:background="#3F51B5"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="Cross"
            android:id="@+id/crossButton"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:background="#3F51B5"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="Dot"
            android:id="@+id/dotButton"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:background="#3F51B5"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="Mag"
            android:id="@+id/magButton"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:background="#3F51B5"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="Reset"
            android:id="@+id/resetButton"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:background="#3F51B5"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"/>

    </GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

At the minute the buttons/edit texts and output are all relative to the screen size because of dpi.

How would I go about adjusting this so it scales to different screen sizes? As this is what happens currently:
This is ideal: [Nexus 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IchU3.png)
This isn't: [Nexus S](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ELWz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this layout instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultOutput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:password="false"
        android:phoneNumber="false"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/resultOutput"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/x1"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:hint="x1"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/x2" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/x2"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:hint="x2"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/x3" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/x3"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:hint="x3"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/y1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/y1"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:hint="y1"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/y2" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/y2"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:hint="y2"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/y3" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/y3"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:hint="y3"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal" />

    </GridLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/gridLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="#3F51B5"
            android:text="Add"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/subButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#3F51B5"
            android:text="Sub"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/unitButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#3F51B5"
            android:text="Unit"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/row1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/crossButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="#3F51B5"
            android:text="Cross"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dotButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#3F51B5"
            android:text="Dot"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/magButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#3F51B5"
            android:text="Mag"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/resetButton"
            android:layout_below="@id/row2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#3F51B5"
            android:text="Reset"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this and the buttons are still positioned all strange. Would the fact I'm using a gridLayout for the buttons be of issue here?

Comment: See my updated response, I replaced the buttons with LinearLayouts and set the same weight to all the buttons.

Answer (score 3):

Since API 21 you can use **android:layout_columnWeight="1"** to distribute excess of space for each element column.

You'll want to asign the same *column weight* in order to fill each column space equally

Check GridLayout android reference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

Section **Excess Space Distribution**

Answer (score 0):

you would use hdpi, xhdpi, etc folders (http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

cheers

Answer (score 0):

**This is usually a very long process:**

You must make separate directories for **every** layout in order to remain consistent to the *user*:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

You have to make different layouts for each screen size, and android automatically sets the layout based on the name of the directory with the contents of your XML file:

**IN  ANDROID STUIDO:**
[image]

**Now, select the size:**

[image]

Do this for every single layout you have:

[image]

(Small is considered pretty obsolete now)

Then, just render your layout in each directory. You don't have to make the directories like that, if you want you can just go into project view and create them and copy the xml files, but this way is much more easy.

Let me know if it helped,

Ruchir

Comment: So would I essentially need to change the visual layout for a variety of devices? Because I have it looking as I want on a OnePlus One and a Nexus 7 thanks to this.

Comment: @Sectah Yep, pretty much. What I do with my app is I optimize for the open space on things like xlarge devices, by adding more content in one layout. Or, you could just increase the size of everything. If this was helpful, please press the checkmark on the left of the answer to accept it. If you need more help, feel free to ask! :)